# Find the number of integer triplets such that $x+y+z=n$ and $x\geq y\geq z > 0$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer such that $n > 3$ and let $S$ be the set of all ordered triples of strictly positive
> integers $(x, y, z)$ whose sum is $n$. Show that $S$ has $\frac{1}{2} (n − 1) (n − 2)$ elements.
>
> Distinguishing cases, find the number of integer triples $(x, y, z)$ such that
> $x + y + z = n$ and $x \geq y \geq z > 0$

I’ve managed to prove the first part, that $S$ has $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)(n-2)$ elements but I am struggling with the latter part.

Comment: This is a common result. Infact the number of non-negative integral solutions for $\sum_{i=1}^r x_i = n$ is given by $\binom{n-1}{r-1}$.

Comment: @Kaind, this trick gives the answer to the first part, which he did correctly.

Comment: @BokaPeer Thanks, I read the question in a hurry I guess.

Comment: Substitute $y=z+n,x=y+m=z+m+n$ where $n,m\ge0$. Now calculate the number of solutions of $3z+2n+m=n$, which is given by the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^3+x^6+x^9+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, Sorry I have not seen your comments when I was writing my answer.  I kind of repeated what you said.

Comment: @BokaPeer It is fine, I have not stated something in my exclusive knowledge.

Comment: That's so kind of you. Sometimes people get mad if they see something repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for the second one:

Find the number of integer triples $(x, y, z)$ such that
$x + y + z = n$ and $x \geq y \geq z > 0$

let $y = z+k_1$ and $x = y+k_2.$ with $k_1, k_2 \geq 0.$ Then we have $3z +2k_1 +k_2 =n.$  Then let $z_1 = z-1$ then $z_1 \geq 0.$ Finally we have $3z_1 + 2k_1+k_2 = n- 3.$  Note that $z_1, k_1, k_2 \geq 0.$

There are standard tricks to solve such an equation. Either you can use the General Principle of Inclusions & Exclusions or the idea of generating functions.

Basically, Shubham Johri gave you the solution before I wrote these hints.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy method that uses your answer to the first part and doesn't reinvent the wheel. Suppose the set containing triples satisfying the second part is denoted by $T\subseteq S$. In $S$ there are triples where:

1. **All $x,y,z$ are distinct.** Suppose there are $m$ such triples in $S$. Such triples permute in $3!=6$ ways, i.e. the unordered triple $(x,y,z)$ makes $6$ appearances in $S$. When $x,y,z$ are ordered in non-increasing order as per the requirement in the second part of the question, we get one unique ordering corresponding to the $6$ appearances. Thus we have $m/6$ triples in $T$ where all coordinates are distinct.
2. **Two coordinates are identical.** Suppose the identical coordinates have value $1$, then the third coordinate has value $n-2$. Corresponding to this selection of values, we have $3!/2!=3$ triples in $S$. Similarly, when $2$ is repeated, the third coordinate is $n-4$ and this selection is repeated $3$ times. The identical coordinates can at most be $\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$ as the third coordinate needs to be at least $1$. Thus the total number of triples in $S$ where two coordinates are identical is $3\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$. Corresponding to these we have $\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$ triples in $T$.

Note that in the second case we would have encountered a triple where all three coordinates are identical had $3\mid n$. This particular triple would not have $3$, but only $1$ occurrence in $S$.
Thus when $3\nmid n$, we have $$m+3\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor=\frac12(n-1)(n-2)\\|T|=m/6+\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$$

And when $3\mid n$, we subtracted $2$ from the $3$ occurrences of the triple $(n/3,n/3,n/3)$ we counted in case $2$ to get$$m+3\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor=\frac12(n-1)(n-2)+2\\|T|=m/6+\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor$$

---

All in all$$|T|=\frac1{12}(n-1)(n-2)+\frac12\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor+\begin{cases}1/3,&3\mid n\\0,&3\nmid n\end{cases}$$

I hope I have not made any errors.